# does Interlocked.Increment count right the number of threads into parallel foreach

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

I just want to count the numeber of threads runnuing into foreach parallel.

i just wrote this code and expect the threads.count is equl to threadsCount is the same, but it is not. the variable threadsCount is always greater than threads.Count. Why?

Also why should i use Interlocked instead of a standard collection like HashSet?

```
int threadsCount = 0;
HashSet<int> threads = new HashSet<int>();

Parallel.ForEach(productConfig.Documenti.Keys, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = MaxNumOfThreads }, key =>
{
  int progress = Interlocked.Increment(ref threadsCount);
  threads.Add(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
});
```

Comment: Parallel uses the threadpool, you simply see the same threadpool thread being used more than once.  Feature, not a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Your interlocked counter is counting keys, not threads. The callback will be invoked on every *key*, and those callbacks will be spread between whatever number of threads it *chooses* to use, at most `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`. It is *not* a thread per key - as threads are very expensive, and there's usually not much point parallelising with more threads than you have CPU cores. Usually, it simply shares the load between some number of pool threads. So yes, we would expect that your interlocked counter ends up at the same number as `productConfig.Documenti.Keys.Count`, and `threads.Count` ends up as being *whatever number of threads actually got used*. We would *expect* that `threads.Count` is usually much less than your counter, unless there are only one or two keys.

Note: `HashSet<T>` is *not* thread-safe, so right now this code could break horribly - you would need to use a concurrent or synchronized data store for that to work reliably.

> Also why should i use Interlocked instead of a standard collection like HashSet?

Why should you use either? why do you care how many threads were used? and why are you counting the keys that *you yourself provided*?

Comment: so if i understand correctly, i need to remove interlocked.increment and replace HashSet with a collection thread safe like ConcurrentBag. is this code safe to add a Thread where threads is ConcurrentBag<int>? if(!threads.Contains(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId))                         threads.Add(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

Comment: @FDB an "if !contains then add" is inherently not thread-safe; that's a race condition; however, you haven't answered the question: *why do you care?*

Comment: I Just want to write to the log at the end of elaboration. It Is not necessary. what about put contains and add into a lock?

Comment: @FDB then you're adding a pointless bottleneck to your parallelism

Comment: How can i check and add if not exists in a safe way woth no bottkeneck?

Comment: @FDB maybe `ConcurrentDictionary<int, bool>`, then `if (!dict.ContainsKey(mgdThdId)) dict[mgdThdId] = true;` - this avoids mutation in the common "already exists" case, and by using indexer rather than add, we don't have a race - just check `.Count` afterwards. It should have *minimal* impact and be thread safe